# List out of range whilst using recursion

Tags: python

Currently making Sudoku in my CompSci class, I'm using recursion to check my rows and make sure that there are no duplicates (I'll do columns and 3x3's later) but I'm running into an issue of my index going out of range. Now I know that means that it's going outside of the list but for some reason I can't figure out how it is.

Here is my recursion method for covering all of the rows. I'm importing a default 0 as the row initially and therefore is goes from 0 all the way to 8 and when it reaches 8, it'll return(essentially a break).

```
def winCheck(self, row):
        if row == 8:
            return ''
        for num in range (1,10): #for EACH values 1-9
            count = 0
            for j in range(9):
                if (self.board[row][j] == str(num)):
                    count += 1
            if (count!=1): #MUST have a count of 1
                print("wrong!")
                return False
            elif count == 1:
                print("good!")
                row= row + 1
                game.winCheck(row)
        return True
```

Here is my list for my playing board and the original board (those can't be modified)

```
for i in range(9):
            self.board[i] = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' ]
            self.origBoard[i] = [' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ', ' ' ]
```

```
# [[' ', '1', '9', '3', '7', '4', '6', '5', '2'],
# ['5', '7', '6', '1', '8', '2', '9', '4', '3'],
# ['3', '4', '2', '5', '9', '6', '7', '1', '8'],
# ['9', '2', '1', '7', '5', '3', '8', '6', '4'],
# ['6', '3', '8', '4', '1', '9', '5', '2', '7'],
# ['4', '5', '7', '6', '2', '8', '1', '3', '9'],
# ['1', '8', '5', '2', '3', '7', '4', '9', '6'],
# ['7', '6', '3', '9', '4', '1', '2', '8', '5'], 
# ['2', '9', '4', '8', '6', '5', '3', '7', ' ']]
#raw data set for testing win conditions
```

Comment: Please don't post images of code/data/Tracebacks.  Just copy the text, paste it in your question and format it as code.

Comment: You're doing `row= row + 1` inside the loop, which iterates 9 times. So `row` could be increased up to 9 times, making it bigger than 8.

Comment: [Catch the error](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions) and inspect/print/log relevant data in the except suite.  Print/log relavent data at strategic points to see what might be happening. Troubleshoot with a smaller board to make it easier. Or visualize execution - http://www.pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=edit

Comment: @kaya3 , Initially I thought that was the problem, but I have a check for if it reaches 8 it should then break the loop right?

Comment: Change the first `for` to `for i in range(0, 9)` to get the nine index items.

Comment: No, because you're only checking if it equals 8 before the loop. There is no such check inside the loop.

Comment: Move the recursive call to `winCheck` to outside of the loop.

Comment: @kaya3, yeah sure. But his `for` is `range(1,10)`, so he is trying index 9, which does not exist (and skipping index 0)

Comment: @EricDay that 1,10 is so I can check for numbers '1-10' in my list, It's the only way for checking suduko

Comment: `game.winCheck(row)` `-->` `return game.winCheck(row)`

Comment: @wwii that fixed it, this is my first time using recursion to actually solve a problem, thanks for the help. (Definitely gonna be reviewing recursion methods on youtube ha!)

Comment: [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: @EricDay `num` isn't used as an index anywhere.

Comment: @kaya3 my bad. Did not read the code properly. Sorry for the confusion, and glad that wwii gave the right suggestion !

Answer (score 0):

game.winCheck(row) --> return game.winCheck(row)

Comment: With that recursive call being where it is in the code, the function will return after the first iteration through the loop. OP has to also move the call to outside of the loop if they want to check all of the numbers for validity.